# How to retrieve only 1 week data from Sq-lite starting from Sunday in Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Below is my code:

Table Creation:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        final String query = "CREATE TABLE " + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.MONEY + " REAL NOT NULL,"
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.CAT + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.DATE + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,"
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TIMESTAMP + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" + "); ";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Query for retrieving 1 week data:

```
private Cursor getAllCurrentData()
    {
        String[] selectArg = new String[]{};
        return db.query(Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TABLE_NAME,
                null ,
                Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.DATE+ "= date('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')",
                selectArg,
                null,
                null,
                Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TIMESTAMP);
    }
```

Problem is I'm not able retrieve 1 week using above query .Please tell me what mistake I'm doing .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.DATE+ "= date('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')",
```

retrieves the rows where `DATE` is equal to the `date()` expression. But it seems like you want all rows where `DATE`is greater than or equal to the expression. Try:

```
Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.DATE+ ">= date('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')",
```

Note the `>=` operator vs the `=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

For retrieve only 1 week Data  we can use below query.This will get filtered Data.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE(timeStamp) >= DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')
```

In our scenario you can use

```
Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.DATE+ ">= date('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')"
```

You have to use operator **greater than equal to**, this will display current week days data. You have used only **equal to**, this will display start of  week first day data.

I hope this will help you !